# Are there any visual changes to Kerrigan when / as she levels up?

Tags: starcraft-2

As you advance in level does Kerrigan's appearance change in any way?

Comment: @Downvoter - Can anyone elaborate to why the question has been considered bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what I saw, until you mutate back to zerg, she doesn't.

Comment: So is here mutation her only change? Interesting...